# is there any argument option that can be passed to eclipse executable?

Tags: eclipse, shared-libraries

I'm executing eclipse on my system by providing the many argument options such as
-vm, -nosplash, -showLocation etc.

Is there any option that will load a shared library before starting eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, you might want to investigate writing your `"shared-library"` as an eclipse plugin, which can be specified to be loaded at start up.

An example from an eclipse.ini file:

```
-startup
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
../../../plugins/your_plugin_here
```

Comment: no I want to load c++ shared library that will be used by JVM  process specified in eclipse start-up  command.

Comment: @BSalunke That is going to be a nice challenge for you. Check this question inspiration: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826942/is-it-possible-to-write-plugin-for-eclipse-other-than-java-in-eclipse